# Setting up TempDB for more than one instance of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, configuration, tempdb

I've been given the task of transferring the contents of a SQL Server instance from one Windows server to another Windows Server. One of the many things I need to do on the new server is set up the TempDB. I have read in many articles that the rule of thumb for the TempDb is to put it on its own drive and create 8 equal sized files that use up most of the disk.
However this applies to where there is only one instance of SQL Server.

The new server has 2 instances of SQL server installed and I've tried to find recommendations for setting up the TempDb files in this situation and I can't find anything.

How should I be setting up the TempDb files in this case? 
Do I just allocate 1/2 of the disk space to each instance and go from there?

The new instances of SQL server are SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for participating. One quick question: What size is the disk/drive that has been dedicated to the TempDB?

Comment: You should place files for each instance on different physical drives at least. In ideal world each file on a separate physical drive.

Comment: What does your underlying storage look like? RAID? Physical drives? A SAN?

Comment: The server is a virtual machine so the underlying storage is disc, currently 100Gb but can be made larger,  The two instances are low usage.

Comment: Why don't you check out the actual tempdb configuration on the existing server to have an idea how big it should be? Who if not you can know how intensively tempdb is used on that server?